# How to disable entire test (including inherited methods) in TestNG

Tags: java, inheritance, reflection, testng

I'm using TestNG framework, and many test classes extends Base abstract Test providing some additional information.

I want to set `@Test(enabled = false)` on whole test class, which is problematic in TestNG as any `@Test` annotation on method will override first one. Which means, even disabled class, all methods will run anyway.

I found workaround provided by framework authors in pull requests [#816](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/pull/816) - add listener, that modifies `@Test` annotations on methods if class that they are defined have `@Test(enabled = false)`:

```
public class TestClassDisabler implements IAnnotationTransformer {

  @Override
  public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor,
                        Method testMethod) {
    if (testMethod != null) {
      Test test = testMethod.getDeclaringClass().getAnnotation(Test.class);
      if (test != null && !test.enabled()) {
        annotation.setEnabled(false);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It works like a charm, however only for tests that don't use inheritance. For this scenario, `testMethod.getDeclaringClass()` from listener returns original class in which method was declared, not class of object instance that started method.

```
@Test(enabled = false)
class SpecificTest extends BaseTest {

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {}
}

abstract class BaseTest {

    @Test
    public void veryGenericTest() {}
}
```

For this example, only `testSomething` is disabled, `veryGenericTest` still runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IAnnotationTransformer` is not good choice here. There is no easy way to get original instance that called method, based only on `Method` interface. We can only get base class in which method was declared.

Other solution works with `IMethodInterceptor`, which allows filtering out methods before test suite starts and provides access to test class instance.

```
public class TestMethodsDisabler implements IMethodInterceptor {

    @Override
    public List<IMethodInstance> intercept(List<IMethodInstance> methods, ITestContext context) {
        List<IMethodInstance> testsToRun = new ArrayList<>();

        for (IMethodInstance method : methods) {
            Test testClass = method.getInstance()
                .getClass()
                .getAnnotation(Test.class);

            if (testClass == null || testClass.enabled()) {
                testsToRun.add(method);
            }
        }

        return testsToRun;
    }
}
```

That way, both standard and inherited methods are disabled when we set `@Test(enabled = false)` annotation on class.

It's needed to create test suite in `testng.xml` with this interceptor:

```
<suite name="ListenersSuite" parallel="false">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="your.package.support.TestMethodsDisabler"/>
    </listeners>

    <test name="all-test" preserve-order="true" verbose="2">
        <packages>
            <package name="your.package.tests.*"/>
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

**Reference**

- [TestNG documentation - method interceptors](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#methodinterceptors)

Comment: You should accept your own answer and close the question.

Comment: @juherr: I had to wait 48h before I could accept my own answer, done. Thanks for reaching out :)